# How to merge two protobuf files efficiently?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

there. I have multiple protocol buffer files (`*.pb`) and a `name.proto` file (proto2). These pb files are in the same protobuf format. I want to merge these pb files into one file. It is ok to use python load all of these files and serialize them to one output. I wonder if there is a more efficient way to merge multiple pb files ?

Answer (score 1):

For more efficient way to merge multiple files, you may try it in bash (if you are using Linux / macOS).

```
cat *.pb name.proto > your_merged_file
```

For Windows systems, you can do this in cmd:

```
type *.pb name.proto > your_merged_file
```